# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject does not properly fill object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing, json-deserialization

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Language>(json)` returns object whose properties are empty. I want to fill the lang object, which should have few properties such as a list of string named 'IncreaseIndent' and others.

**Indentor.json**

```
{"VBA":[
  { "IncreaseIndent":["Public Sub *","Public Function *","If *then","While *","Do","Do while *","For *","With *","Select Case *","Sub *","Function *","* Type *","Private Sub *","Private Function *","* Enum *"]},
  { "DecreaseIndent":["End Sub","End Function","End if","Wend","Loop While *","Loop","Next","Next *","End With","End Select","End Type","End Enum"] },
  { "Exception":["Elseif *","Else","Case *","Case"]}
]}
```

**C#**

```
public static string FormatCode(string strCode)
{
    Language lang;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("A:/standardvba/Logic/Indentor.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        lang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Language>(json); //Inside lang every property is null
        return IndentCodePiece(strCode, lang);
    }
}

public class Language
{
    public string ProgrammingLanguage { get; set; }
    public List<string> IncreaseIndent { get; set; }
    public List<string> DecreaseIndent { get; set; }
    public List<string> Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong. Your Json is not valid. Check here ""IncreaseIndent":"Public Sub *","Public Function *"" to begin with

Comment: It is naive of you to point the problem without providing the solution. The error tells the problem, not the solution, and we are all here for solutions.

Comment: I agree, but only to an extend. Its important we also allow the developer to discover the issue himself when it is there in plain sight to see and hence point to exact piece of code where he needs to be look. That's why I had pointed to the exact place in the JSON where the error begins. The OP didnt mention you wanted to know how to represent the list (comma separation in value). Apologies if you felt otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have JSON in wrong format, `IncreaseIndent`, `DecreaseIndent` and `Exception` should be lists of strings:

```
{"VBA":[
    { "IncreaseIndent":["Public Sub *","Public Function *",...] },
    { "DecreaseIndent":["End Sub","End Function", ...] },
    { "Exception":["Elseif *","Else","Case *","Case"] }
]}
```

I added **[** after II, DI and Ex and added **]** at the end of each value!

you can validate josn on page https://jsonlint.com and you'll see that validation will fail. If you introduce changes I proposed validation is OK!

Comment: Somebody was quick to correct answer my formatting so thank you :)

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please provide a solution now.